# How do you call a local function?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

So heres the basic outline

```
function x(){
   // some code 
   function y(){
   //some more code
  }
}

function z(){
  // how do i call function y?
}
```

I tried

```
function z(){
   window[x][y];
} 

and

function z(){
x();y();
}
```

neither works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lots of code, not much explanation.

```
function x(){
   // some code 
   function y(){
   //some more code
  }
}
```

The above declares *y* inside *x*, so it is created as a property of *x*'s variable object each time *x* is called. *y* can only be accessed from inside *x* unless code inside *x* makes it available from elsewhere.

```
function z(){
  // how do i call function y?
}
```

To call *y* from inside *z*, it must be available on *z*'s scope chain. That can be done by passing it in the function call (making it a property of *z*'s variable object) or making it a property of some object on *z*'s scope chain.

If the function is to be available to both functions, it makes sense to declare it where it can be accessed by both *x* and *z*, or initialize *z* in such a manner that *y* is available. e.g.

```
var z;
var x = (function() {
  function y(){}

  z = function() {
        // something that calls y;
      };

  return function() {
    // x function body
  }
}());
```

In the above, *x* and *z* both have access to the same *y* function and it is not created each time *x* is called. Note that *z* will be undefined until the code assigning to *x* is executed.

Note also that *y* is **only** available to *x* and *z*, it can't be accessed by any other function (so *y* might be called a *private* function and *x* and *z* might be called *privileged* functions).

Answer (score 3):

## 1:

```
var ref;
function x(){
   // some code 
   function y(){
   //some more code
  }
  ref = y;
}
x();

function z(){
  ref();
}
```

## 2:

```
function x() {
};

x.y = function() { alert('2');};

function z() {  x.y(); }
```

## 3:

```
function y(){ alert('god'); };
function x() {
    function a() {
        y();
    }
}
function z() {
      y();
}
z();
```

Comment: but this adds `ref` in the global namespace

Comment: ahh, it was only a matter of time before the global namespace crew arrived. i'm giving a primitive example, realistically he should use a self executing anonymous function around the code, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
function x(){
   // some code 
  this.y=function(){
   //some more code
  }
}

function z(){
 var fun_x=new x();
fun_x.y();
}
```

the global namespace is still as it was before this code

Comment: Except that if *x* is not called as a constructor (and the code isn't in strict mode), a *y* property will be added to the global/window object.

Comment: @RobG But in the code `x` is called as a constructor and the property `y` will be added to whatever object the context is set to while calling `x`

Comment: Context? The execution context is irrelevant. BTW, following the assignment: `var fun_x = new x();` should be 'fun_x.y();`.