# Javascript: Access a subfunction of function a() inside function b()

Tags: javascript, function

I have following **Javascript** code, and am trying to 
***access the subfunction of function a() inside function b()***, could anybody guide me as how can this be achieved.

```
function a() {

    function a1(pos) {
        // code
        // return some value
    }
}

function b() {
    if (condition) {
        // call a1
        var value = a(a1('side'));
    }
}
```

Currently trying this way gives me error that a1 is undefined.

I understand its related with, so could someone shed some light on these matters, as I tried online but couldn't find satisfying explanation.

***a. Syntax to call a function***

***b. Scope of a function***

Comment: This is not possible. `a1` is inside a closure, there's no way to access it outside of `a`.

Comment: @elclanrs: It has more something to do with local scope of a function than with closure.

Comment: a) You call a function by adding `()` after a reference to it. E.g. `func();`. b) A function has access to any symbol defined in its own scope or that is accessible in the scope it was defined in (closure). As already mentioned, it is not possible to access `a1` from outside `a`, since `a1` is *local* to the function. But even if you would make it global, at the moment you try to call `a1`, it does no exist yet.

Comment: @FelixKling: Well, yeah I guess that's the case here. It's all about semantics really because in JS is kinda `scope == closure == function`...

Comment: Thanks @elclanrs and Felix for clarifying my head, found a workaround here [[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921010/how-do-you-call-a-local-function]] .

Comment: @felix Is there point in accepting [at]dropout's answer, as his answer is just what your guys said

Comment: If you find his answer helpful you can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible AFAIK, the a1 function is out of scope. To use a1 you have to take it into scope by extracting it to the same "level" as other functions. Something like this:

```
function a1(){...}

function a(){a1(); ...}

function b()
{
    if(condition)
    {
        a1();
        ...
    }    
}
```